# How does Rails know that migrations are pending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

In Rails, sometimes we get the error

`ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError`

How does Rails know migrations are pending?

Where is that flag/information stored?

Comment: check your database, there's a table `schema_migrations`. See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) and [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057408/how-does-rails-keep-track-of-which-migrations-have-run-for-a-database?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

When model or migration is created a time-stamp is added along to the filename.

```
         20160727050119_create_user.rb
         #time-stamp 20160727050119
```

Then a method `call(env)` that retrieve the last migration stamp.

```
       `mtime = ActiveRecord::Migrator.last_migration.mtime.to_i`
```

and compare it to `@last_check` and if it is less than `mtime`

`check_pending!` is called and `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` is shown.

```
       ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!(connection)
```

**check_pending!**

```
      def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
        raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
      end
```

You can find all this info `.../lib/active-record/migration.rb`

Comment: Useful info, and explains an issue I was having: If you're committing your schema.rb file and fail to commit the version parameter to `ActiveRecord::Schema.define` at the top of the file along with your other changes, it can cause others (in my case the CI system) to get the pending migration error when they try to run the tests, because the schema version is less than the timestamp on the most recent migration.

Answer (score 5):

There is a table in your application's database called **schema_migrations**, that has a single column called versions. There will be a row for every migration that has been run. If there is a migration file on disc, whose timestamp is not included in the **schema_migrations** table, then Rails knows that migrations need to be run.

Comment: I wonder how do you know about that - the official guide does not say a word about it: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: Well, I've been working with Rails full time for the last 14 years so am quite familiar with how it works. The schema_migration is actually mentioned in passing the "Old Migrations" section of the migrations guide.