# Migration not working in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason or another my Ruby on Rails application is telling me that it can't run migrations. I an unsure how to fix this. I created a table with no information by accident. I then tried to delete the migration file and the table that it created. When I try to run the migration command it gives me this error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migration' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue. I need to remove the existing table so that I can create the correct one. It won't populate my schema file.

This is the error that I get when I run rake db:migrate

```
rake db:migrate
```

== 20170322214259 CreateProfiles: migrating ===================================
-- change_table(:profiles)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL: ALTER TABLE "profiles" ADD "created_at" datetime NOT NULL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in`execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in`block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in`log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in`add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1096:in`add_timestamps'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:525:in `timestamps'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:11:in`block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in`block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:3:in`change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in`with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in`within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in`transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`block (2 levels) in '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL: ALTER TABLE "profiles" ADD "created_at" datetime NOT NULL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in`block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in`execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in`add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1096:in `add_timestamps'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:525:in`timestamps'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:11:in `block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in`change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in`method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in`exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in`block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in`block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in`block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in`transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in`block in migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in`up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
SQLite3::SQLException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in`execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in`block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in`log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in`add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:1096:in`add_timestamps'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:525:in `timestamps'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:11:in`block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in`block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/db/migrate/20170322214259_create_profiles.rb:3:in`change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in`with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in`within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in`transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`block (2 levels) in '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: try `rake db:migrate` instead of `rake db:migration`

Comment: When you run a migration and want to remove it, you should also run `rake db:rollback` instead of deleting the migration file and dropping the table in the DB manually. Once you've rolled it back you can delete the file if you want. Rails uses a `schema_migrations` table in your DB to track what migrations have run or haven't. If you don't rollback the table think the migration has run already. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12057445/3366016  Not recommended but you can also go into the DB and mess with the schema_migrations table but again, not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment suggesting you use `rake db:migrate` instead of `rake db:migration`:

I also suggest you look into rake [db:rollback](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back) if you find you've made a mistake while generating your model/migration.

Comment: I have tried that. After I run the db:rollback command I delete the migration file. I then generate a new migration file and fill it with the correct information so that it creates a table with the correct columns. After I save that file I try to run rails db:migrate and I get the "Cannot create table, profiles table already created." error.

Comment: After you run `db:rollback`, don't delete the migration file and generate a new migration file. Just edit the migration file that you've previously created.  From your error, you likely now have multiple migration files that are trying to create the `profiles` table. Make sure you only have one migration that has `create_table :profiles`.

Comment: How do I get rid of the excess migration files? So that it only sees the one file.

Comment: Nothing I do is fixing this issue. I have destroyed the migration. I have used the rollback command. I have even found the file using db:migrate:status and destroyed the missing file there. I can't seem to fix my migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've used migration instead of migrate
`rake db:migrate`