# Rails set default DateTime to now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have teams and each team has a game time every week. I want the game times to be set to 'now' as a default. My table is set up like so

```
create_table "teams", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "wk1_time"
end
```

I created a migration and it looks like this:

```
class ChangeDateTimeDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :teams, :wk1_time, :default => DateTime.now
  end
end
```

When I run rake db:migrate I get an error. Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something else?

Comment: what is the error.. paste here please

Comment: @ArupRakshit undefined method `to_sym'

Comment: I gave you explanations.. check out please.. :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580805/how-to-set-the-default-value-for-a-datetime-column-in-migration-script/40647191#40647191

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value for a datetime column to record creation time in a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580805/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-a-datetime-column-to-record-creation-time-in-a-mi)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the **type** :

```
class ChangeDateTimeDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :teams, :wk1_time, :datetime, :default => DateTime.now
  end
end
```

But, you need the below not the above one, because you just want to change the *default*.

```
class ChangeDateTimeDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default :teams, :wk1_time, DateTime.now
  end
end
```

But none of these are correct approach for your task. The reason is `DateTime.now` will be evaluated based upon when you ran the migration, instead when the record is created. You need look to into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580805/2767755) to know how to set the default time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357711/733755 is the better answer

Answer (score 22):

[Since Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27077) you can make a migration like this:

```rb
change_column_default :users, :wk1_time, -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }
```

In my mind this is the best option because it not database specific answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Rails 6 as well

Comment: When you run this migration, Rails serializes it to `"now()"` in `schema.rb`. It seems they are equivalent.

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: For Rails 5+ there are better answers, like this one:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357711/252799, though the below still works.

The way I found, was to do a migration *on an existing datetime column*, like this:

```
#migration
execute("ALTER TABLE teams ALTER COLUMN wk1_time SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

that produces a schema.rb entry shown like this:

```
#schema.rb
t.datetime "wk1_time",                    default: "now()", null: false
```

The `"now()"` is a string sent to postgresql and evaluated at runtime, upon each insert.

Comment: If you downvote, please tell me why, this is a forum for education. I'll treat you with respect, I know I'm not always right. The solution presented here, worked for us, I am not pulling it as long as I think it's helpful to others.

Comment: FWIW, at least on Rails 6, this doesn't work because it's not in a lambda. To make this work it needs to be:
`default: -> { "now()" }`

Comment: @kroehre The `"now()"` is evaluated in PG, not Ruby. The answer still works as it isn't dependent on any Rails version, though in Rails 5 this can be done Ruby-side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647191/252799

Comment: This didn't work for me without the lambda in Rails 6. The column ended up without any default and it raised an error complaining about null values. Adding the lambda fixed the issue.

Comment: a lambda to the `execute` doesn't make sense... you probably misunderstood and put the schema result into a migration.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to run into problems settings the default date time in the migration. This is because `DateTime.now` will be evaluated based upon when the migrate runs, not when the record is created!

To fix that you'll need to create an ActiveRecord callback in order to set `wk1_time` like so:

```
before_create :set_default_wk1_datetime
def set_default_wk1_datetime
  self.wk1_time = DateTime.now
end
```

Answer (score 1):

for Postgresql :

```
add_column :users, :msgs_seen_at, 'TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

but you'll have to use `user.reload` after `user = User.create` in order to "see" msgs_seen_at

Answer (score 0):

in rails 7 you should do the following (in case you want your timestamp to be evaluated each time when the row is being inserted)

`db/migrate/20240215142705_alter_table_teams.rb`

```rb
add_column :teams, :wk1_time, :timestamp, null: false, default: -> { "now()" }
```

which results the follwing structure

```sql
wk1_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer, default: 100, null: false
    add_column :table_name, :column_name_date_to_save, :datetime, default: DateTime.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?